# Postman 400 bad request

Tags: json, http-headers, restlet, postman

I am using postman client app for a rest-let of POST type request.
for my URL, I am passing a query-Parameter.
When I pass a small JSON string  as value it is been passed perfectly fine , but when I pass a large JSON string as value it throws an error of Bad Request 400 error. Not able to figure out what is going wrong and how to debug and fix the issue.

Can some one help me?

thank you.
~Sha

Answer (score 1):

How large is large? Have you ensured that your query value is URL encoded? Try encoding your value and see if that helps. Here is an online tool to encode your JSON value if you're not familiar with how to do this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove new line, maybe it will help.
fixed in my case.[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KLgN.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32051887)